# Opening a web browser in Qt mobile application

Tags: qt

My application is about opening a desired webpage when a user clicks on a button on the UI. I am developing this application basically for N900.
Any suggestion would be appreciated .
Thanx in advance

Answer (score 1):

if you want to open web page in application then you can use [QWebView](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qwebview.html) or if you want to open webpage in external browser you can use [QDesktopServices](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/QDesktopServices.html)

like this

```
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl("http://www.google.com", QUrl::TolerantMode));
```

Comment: #include "widget.h"
#include "ui_widget.h"
#include<QPushButton>
#include<QDesktopServices>
#include<QUrl>
#include<QtWebKit/QWebView>

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    QPushButton *b=new QPushButton("Click me",this);
    connect(b,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(brow()));
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
    delete ui;
}
void Widget::brow()
{
    
    QWebView::load(QUrl(tr("http://www.rtiindia.org/forum/forum.php")));


}

Comment: you did not mentioned what kind of error, and can you also update your question with code and error and what you tried ?